# Pushing differently-sized registers to the stack

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

While looking through [Intel's Instruction Set Reference](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325383.pdf), I noticed that the the opcodes for pushing a 16-, 32-, and 64-bit register are the same (`50+rw`, `50+rd`, and `50+rd`, respectively).

How does the processor know which register it needs to push to the stack if all of the opcodes are the same? If it depends on the current operating mode, then if you push `ax` in protected mode, are the upper 16 bits of `eax` pushed to the stack, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumptions is slightly off (I don't blame you, intels manuals can very very cryptic sometimes), yes, they may have the same *base* opcode, but sizes differing from 32 require a size override prefix, eg:

```
66:50 PUSH AX
50    PUSH EAX
```

Here we can see the 16 bix size override prefix, `0x66`, is used when `PUSH`'ing `AX`.

this is one reason you can't push byte registers, cause there is no size override prefix available to do this.